# Проблемы со шрифтом на Github Pages

Tags: html, css, github

При запуске локального сервера всё в порядке, но github pages не видит шрифт BravoRG и выдаёт ошибку, никаких нижних подчёркиваний перед названием папки или файла я не использую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/CyberLiberast/Luxtrader__landing - репозиторий
https://cyberliberast.github.io/Luxtrader__landing/ - сайт

Comment: Шрифт запрашивается из папки `fonts/BravoReG`, а в вашем репозитории такой нет.

Comment: В стилях изменил путь на "BravoReg" с маленькой буквы g, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, почистите кэш браузера